# How to change color of the elements in the array?

Tags: javascript

I want to change each element in the set to red color. I don't know but my solution doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length;++i){
arr[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 0, 0)"; // I want to set i element in the array to color red

}
```

Comment: `rgb(0,0,0)` is black.

Comment: It doesn't matter...

Comment: @user3768632 It does if you want them red not black...

Comment: numbers do not have a `style` property. Are you trying to style actual dom elements? (div, for example)

Comment: Well I want to style each number in the array. Then, after the loop I insert all the elements into DOM element: div.innerHTML = arr.join(" "); All works fine, but I don't know how to color the elements.

Answer (score -2):

You'll need to create HTML elements to insert into the DOM. As it is now, it's all JS.

```
var body = document.querySelector("body");
for (int i = 1; i<=4;i++){
    var node = document.createTextNode(i);
    node.style.color = "red";
    body.appendChild(node);
}
```